# Entity Framework one-to-many saves data, but can`t get

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, one-to-many

I have WPF application working with tables. I use a SQLite database with 2 tables with one-to-many relation ship. All data is saved by the program, but when I open program next time every `Project` field  `ICollection<Budget> ProgectBudgets` has 0 items, but there are a lot of items in the database.

Here is the code:

class ViewModel for WPF with use databinding with tables. Also it saves the data

```
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Projects = context.Projects.ToList();
    }

    public List<Project> Projects { get { return projects; } set { projects = value; OnPropertyChanged("Projects"); } }

    private List<Project> projects;

    public void Save()
    {
        foreach (var item in Projects)
        {
            context.Entry(item).State = item.Id == 0 ?
                              EntityState.Added :
                              EntityState.Modified;
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get { return id; } set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Id"); } }
    private int id;
    private string projectName;
    public string ProjectName { get { return projectName; } set { projectName = value; OnPropertyChanged("ProjectName"); } }
    public double Amount { get { return amount; } set { amount = value; OnPropertyChanged("Amount"); } }
    private double amount;
    public virtual ICollection<Budget> ProjectBudget { get; set; }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Project()
    {
        ProjectBudget = new List<Budget>();
    }
}

class Budget
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public double Part { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public Budget()
    {
    }
}

class BudgetsContext : DbContext
{
    public BudgetsContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When you say there is lots of data in the database, are these new budgets that you saved using the above code, or existing budget records you associated to a project?  Please provide whatever mapping you are using. Your Budget entity had neither a Project navigation property or a ProjectId column defined so from what was provided I don't see how EF is associating the two.

Comment: You need to provide a way for EF to [load related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). Try doing `Projects = context.Projects.Include(p => p.ProjectBudget).ToList();`